# Creating index on Azure Cosmodb Mongodb fails with: Fields in 'spatialIndexes' are only allowed with newer API versions

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to create an index using .Net MongoDB.Driver 2.10.0 using the following code:

```
var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<Execution>.IndexKeys.Combine(
    Builders<Execution>.IndexKeys.Ascending(a => a.ClientId),
    Builders<Execution>.IndexKeys.Ascending(a => a.ProjectId),
    Builders<Execution>.IndexKeys.Ascending(a => a.Deleted)
);
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Execution>(indexKeysDefinition));
```

This is creating the following command:

```
{ "createIndexes" : "xxx-execution", "indexes" : [{ "key" : { "ClientId" : 1, "ProjectId" : 1, "Deleted" : 1 }, "name" : "ClientId_1_ProjectId_1_Deleted_1" }] }
```

And results in the following error:

```
Command createIndexes failed: Message: {"Errors":["Fields in 'spatialIndexes' are only allowed with newer API versions. Update your API version from '2018-06-18' to '2018-09-17' leverage this new feature."]}
```

The type of the fields are string and boolean. I cannot find anything on this error. The document does have some spatial fields however I am not using them in the index/query.

Comment: What version is the mongodb server?

Comment: Cosmos DB's MongoDB API has different versions, which you can select when creating your Cosmos DB account. Have you tried creating a new one and choosing the latest api version, then attempting to create a spatial index on that?

Comment: Looking in the azure portal it is 3.2. @DavidMakogon I'm not trying to create a spatial index, do you think the upgrade should be needed?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix or workaround for this? We ran into the same issue today.

Comment: @GoodwinSQL I never figured it out. I ended up not using indexes and eventually switched to RavenDb to reduce costs.